# Question about number of generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, integer-partitions

I know that the generating function for the number of integer partitions of $n$ into distinct parts is
$$\sum_{n \ge 0} p_d(n)x^n = \prod_{i \ge 1}(1+x^i)$$
I'm trying to use this generating function to show that the number of integer partitions of $n$ into parts not divisible by $d$ equals the number of integer partitions of $n$ in which no part appears more than $d-1$ times. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Welcome to mse! What have you tried? Do you have any ideas of your own? Once we have a better idea of exactly where you're struggling, we can help you better ^_^

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glaisher%27s_theorem

Comment: The Wikipedia article on Glaisher's theorem has a simple brief proof.